# catch access requests

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, permissions

Are the sent access requests stored somewhere? In our setup, the site owners do not have full control rights. The access requests go into their mailbox, when approved, they forward them to the admin team, who can actually grant the access rights.

Are the original access request stored in a list, so we can track somehow make a connection between our mailbox and this list and keep the status of the access requests?

Update:
The Access requests and invitations option is missing from the options under Site Permissions on site settings. On some of the sites, we have access requests disabled (also on the top site of the site collection), can this be the reason why I am missing this possibility?

Answer (score 1):

To Approve/ Reject / Track your previous access requests you should be a `Site Owner with Full Control` or `Site Collection Administrator`

**To Track your previous access requests, you can check the requests History as the following:**

- As a `Site Owner with Full Control` go to Site Setting.
- Users and Permissions > Access requests and invitations.

[image]

- At Access Requests page,

  - You can Approve/Reject the access requests.

[image]

- You can Track the Previous Requests and its status by click on **Show History**

[image]

---

You can also use the below links to manage your access request:

- To show **History List**, navigate to

  - `http://sitecollectionurl/Access%20Requests/oldreq.aspx`
- To show **Pending Requests**, navigate to

  - `http://sitecollectionurl/Access%20Requests/pendingreq.aspx`

---

**Note:**

There are four main reasons that disallow the `'Access Requests and Invitations'` to be shown below `Users And Permissions`

1. **Outgoing email setting** is not configured in Central Administration.
2. The **Allow Access Requests** is not enabled in Site Permission.
3. You don't have a sufficient permission like `Owner with Full control` or `Site Collection Administrator`.
4. You have not received any Access Requests before,

   - The `'Access Requests and Invitations'` link didn't appear below `Users And Permissions` until someone actually requests to access the site.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85474/discussion-on-answer-by-mohamed-el-qassas-mvp-catch-access-requests).